# using exception to store user input as either double or string

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop, try-catch, except

Okay, I am very new to try-except.  I do-not know if what i'm trying to do is possible, but thought i'd ask for input anyway.

My program is supposed to average x amount of user inputs until he/she enters q.

Here is the function that is giving me the most problems.

vector user_input()
{

```
    vector<double> scores;
    string user_command;
    do{
        double user_input;
        cout << "Enter the scores to be averaged (range 0-100) or enter q to quit: " << endl;
        cin >> user_command;
        if (is_number(user_command))
        {
            user_input = atof(user_command.c_str());
            if (user_input < 0 || user_input > 100)
                cout << "This is not within range!" << endl;
            else{
                scores.push_back(user_input);}
        }

    }
    while (user_command != "q" && user_command != "Q");
    return scores;
```

}

I need some insight on why this program won't compile.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to fix your syntax first. You're missing `;` at the end of the first `cout <<` line, and you're missing some braces.

Comment: You're also missing the `catch` blocks for your `try` statements.

Comment: There's about a million things wrong with the example, -1 until example is fixed.

Comment: Where are you getting `is_number` from?

Comment: sorry for the mistakes, I'm unfortunately not used to looking at vim yet, and i find it extremely hard to read. I stupidly didn't try compiling before uploading that snippet.

i updated the code to work without exception blocks, but it isn't what the assignment called for.  The function now works, but is it possible to try to insert it into the double first and after it fails, insert their input into a string instead?

Comment: What are the exact requirements of the assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't clearly specified your requirements which makes it difficult to know how to answer the question. I'm assuming you want something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

typedef double score_type;  //so we don't need to write 'double' everywhere, makes it easy to change the type

void user_input(std::vector<score_type>& scores)
{
    std::string command;

    for (;;)
    {
        score_type score;

        std::cout << "Enter the scores to be averaged (range 0-100) or enter q to quit: " << std::endl;

        std::cin >> command;

        if (command == "q" || command == "Q")
        {
            //works better than a do-while in this case
            break;
        }

        try
        {
            //stod to throw std::invalid_argument and std::out_of_range, check documentation (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)
            score = std::stod(command.c_str());
        }
        catch (std::exception e)
        {
            //build exception string
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << "bad input: " << command;

            //throw new exception to be handled elsewhere
            throw std::exception(oss.str().c_str());
        }

        if (score < 0 || score > 100)
        {
            std::cerr << "Input  is not within range (0-100)!" << std::endl;
        }

        scores.push_back(score);
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        std::vector<score_type> scores;

        try
        {
            user_input(scores);
        }
        catch (std::exception e)
        {
            std::cout << "input exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }

        score_type score_sum = 0;

        for (auto score : scores)
        {
            score_sum += score;
        }

        score_type average_score = 0;

        if (!scores.empty())
        {
            average_score = score_sum / scores.size();
        }

        std::cout << "average score: " << average_score << std::endl;
        std::cout << "go again? (y/n): " << std::endl;

        std::string command;

        std::cin >> command;

        if (command == "y")
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (command == "n")
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In future, make sure all the code you post in future questions can be compiled and ran by anyone, especially for simple stuff like this. You can use http://ideone.com/ to test your code samples before posting.